# Proof that in a smooth manifold every open set has same cardinality?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

The manifold of $\Bbb R^n$ with its usual topology certainly has this property, every open set has the same size as every other open set, so there exists a bijection between any two open sets. But, does the fact that a smooth manifold is locally homeomorphic to some euclidean space imply that every open set has same cardinality?

I'm not able to prove it because the definition says that it is *locally* homeomorphic, but I think it is because every open set has a representation, in one chart or another so it must be the same as some open set in $\Bbb R^n$. Is this right?

Comment: Isn't this immediate from the fact that for each $n$ and for each nonempty open set $U$ in ${\mathbb R}^{n},$ the cardinality of $U$ is $c$ (and any homeomorphism is a bijection)? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you require your manifolds to be second-countable, then it is true that every nonempty open subset of a manifold of positive dimension has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.  Indeed, suppose $M$ is a manifold of dimension $n>0$.  Since $M$ is a manifold, it has a basis of open sets that are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and thus have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.  By second-countability, this basis can be chosen to be countable.  Any open subset of $M$ is a union of countably many basis sets.  So, any open subset has cardinality at most $\aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.  Conversely, any nonempty open subset contains at least one basis set and so has cardinality at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.

(Of course, this is false for $0$-dimensional manifolds since you could take a discrete space of any countable cardinality which has open subsets of all smaller cardinalities.  It also fails if you do not require second-countability since then you could take a disjoint union of more than $2^{\aleph_0}$ copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$.)